# PayPal Rest API date filtering not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: paypal

I am using the ruby paypal rest api and everything I do seems to be right but PayPal keeps saying my date format is incorrect.

Here is my call:

```
Payment.all(:start_time => '2013-03-06T11:00:00Z', :end_time => '2013-03-06T11:00:00Z')
```

After many attempts I literally took the date example in the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Because no matter what I do I keep getting the same response:

```
'{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"start_time","issue":"Must
be a date_time string of form yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss(.sss)?Z"},{"field":"end_time","issue":"Must
be a date_time string of form yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss(.sss)?Z"}],"message":"Invalid
request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"dcd8a9ce6a5e7"}'
```

Am I blind or does it not make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in our API where it's expecting raw value rather than url encoded value. The SDK was always url encoding the value of the start_time and end_time (or as a matter of fact all url parameters as per the HTTP spec). We have filed a bug and get this fixed as soon as possible. Meanwhile if this is something you need to work, we can possibly make the SDK not url encode the params or you can just modify the code for now locally.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was going crazy for a second. :-)

Comment: @Praveen: is this another bug in Paypal API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158289/paypal-internal-server-error-when-capturing-payment-with-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

I think your  issue might be that you're setting both the start time and the end time to the same exact value.  If you want a single day's worth of transactions the end time would be 2013-03-06T23:59:59Z.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I used the same end and start time while doing a sanity check. I was expected a response of 200 but with no results. 
To use your example I tried the following:
    `Payment.all(:start_time => '2013-03-06T11:00:00Z', :end_time => '2013-03-06T23:59:59Z')`
and get the same result: `{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"start_time","issue":"Must
        be a date_time string of form yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss(.sss)?Z"},{"field":"end_time","issue":"Must
        be a date_time string of form yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss(.sss)?Z"}]`