# Paypal Internal Server Error when capturing payment with rest api

Tags: rest, paypal

I have this issue in a C#-based project, but I can reproduce it with curl as well. The code was working a few days ago but now it isn't and I'm pretty sure I haven't changed it.

I have a payment that has been authorized and I have its ID, which is correct (when I close the transaction with their online tool I get AUTHORIZATION_ALREADY_COMPLETED instead of Server 500 error).

Here's what I do with curl to repro it, sensitive info redacted:

```
    // check if the AUTHIDHERE code is correct:
curl -v -X GET https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/AUTHIDHERE -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer BEARER123"
```

the above call works and returns:
    {
        "id": "AUTHIDHERE",
        "create_time": "2013-07-17T21:17:58Z",
        "update_time": "2013-07-17T21:18:00Z",
        "state": "authorized",
        "amount": {
            "total": "1.35",
            "currency": "USD",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "1.35"
            }
        },
        "parent_payment": "PAY-SOMELONGIDHERE",
        "valid_until": "2013-08-15T21:17:58Z",
        "links": ...whole bunch here]}
    }

then I call the capture

```
curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/AUTHIDHERE/capture \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer BEARER123" \
-d '{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"1.32"},"is_final_capture":true}
```

and I get this with HTTP 500 status:

```
{
    "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "message": "An internal service error has occurred",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
    "debug_id": "7edadeba20509"
}
```

Some other debug_id values are: 062fc6964d9a8, 6eebc751504eb

Answer (score 0):

quick update: interestingly they all failed in the underlying acquirer call - trying to figure out what went wrong.

Are these all debug_ids associated with the same authorization_id ?

Comment: Yes they are. I have a list of some 30+ authorization IDs that fail. The exact same code on my part worked for 2 payments in the last 7 days and failed for most. If you need more debug IDs or ones associated with different authorizations please let me know.

Comment: a few more would help to verify if they all are related to the same issue we are seeing. Basically what we found is that your PayPal account is not on-boarded for credit card processing. Did you enable Payments capability for your app on the developer.paypal.com website ?

Comment: Yes, it was enabled at when we launched the beta test of our product and some payments have gone through. Here are a few more: [auth= 5XB80...; debug_id=e04caeb4fbf5c] [a=9871...; debug=0d9554f0fca0a] [a=9163...; debug=04fb789dfc54d] [a=49W9...; debug=a62f6b4bfd264]

Comment: I just checked with developer.paypal and the account is "approved", with green checkmarks on both cards and paypal payments, stating "Enabled for test and live"

Comment: thanks @StenPetrov for sending me the details (sorry had to delete my previous comment since I put in my work email id). Found the bug in code - filed it and escalated to get it fixed ASAP. Will give you an update as soon as possible. sorry for the troubles and thank you for helping me troubleshoot this.