# What happens if somebody submits a real Paypal payment to my Sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm stumbling through the Sandbox for testing, but doing it in a (secret) location on the Web so I can test live.

Now I'm curious: I have created both a test vendor and test user for this testing, but the site is actually live. What would happen if somebody with a real Paypal account were to place an order while I were still getting my Paypal form sent to the test vendor account?

Answer (score 1):

They wouldn't be able to login with their PayPal credentials.
And if they were (or signed up for an account whilst in Sandbox), they wouldn't be charged any money whatsoever.

Of course, it's advisable to place a banner / intro on your page advising potential visitors that the site is not currently taking any payments / is in a testing mode.

Comment: ik it's not related but since I can't message... Can you please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158289